# WPF, moving XAML files to another project

Tags: wpf, user-controls, compiler-errors, prism-4

I just moved a couple of WPF User controls from one project to another and now I get all these errors when I compile, the same namespaces are said to be missing from all the user controls CodeDom, Windows, Diagnostics and ComponentModel

```
Error   9   The type or namespace name 'CodeDom' does not exist in the namespace 'Brodit.Etikettsystem.Modules.System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\Users\per\Desktop\Etikettsystem\Brodit.Etikettsystem.Modules\obj\Debug\Customers\CustomersView.g.cs  48  17  Brodit.Etikettsystem.Modules
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'Windows' does not exist in the namespace 'Brodit.Etikettsystem.Modules.System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\Users\per\Desktop\Etikettsystem\Brodit.Etikettsystem.Modules\obj\Debug\Customers\CustomersView.g.cs  40  49  Brodit.Etikettsystem.Modules
Error   7   The type or namespace name 'Diagnostics' does not exist in the namespace 'Brodit.Etikettsystem.Modules.System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\Users\per\Desktop\Etikettsystem\Brodit.Etikettsystem.Modules\obj\Debug\Customers\CustomersView.g.cs  47  17  Brodit.Etikettsystem.Modules
```

After the move I changed all the namespaces to match the new project name, I've tried deleting the obj folder and running custom tool for all the xaml files. Any ideas on what I should do to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

These are .NET Framework namespaces. It looks like some WPF and System libraries are missing from the target project.

Have you tried to copy the XAML files to a Class library project? If so, you should add the proper references to the target project.

Another possibility is that your project targets .NET Framework 2.0 which doesn't include the WPF libraries.

Most System.Windows classes (including [Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.aspx)) are defined in PresentationFramework.dll

Comment: Thanks for replying! The target project is a WPF User Controls project so all the references are there as far as I can see. PresentationCore, PresentationFramework, WindowsBase etc. I have another project in the solution with the exact same set of references that do compile

Comment: And do the view files contain the proper using statements? Try to open the files specified in the message to see what they contain. The compiler can't find the using statements in the files and tries to find the namespaces in the project's default namespace. The .g.cs files are generated by Visual Studio for each .xaml file before compilation.

Comment: Everything looks ok, the project I moved to already had a couple of xaml files that did compile before I moved the other ones in there.

Comment: Aw man! I looks like the problem is MY namespace    `Brodit.Etikettsystem.Modules.System` I changed the `System` part to `SystemModules` and now it all compiles. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

I looks like the problem is MY namespace `Brodit.Etikettsystem.Modules.System` I changed the `System` part to `SystemModules` and now it all compiles.